# Assembly instance with no types in it

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies

How do I get Assembly reference for a .dll with no types in it?

var assembly = typeof (SomeType).Assembly;  --> but without having to spacify any type?

Something like Assembly.Get("AssemblyName");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [Assembly.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load.aspx), [Assembly.LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfile.aspx) or [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom.aspx). There are differences between each .

According to [Suzanne Cook](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/09/19/loadfile-vs-loadfrom.aspx)

> LoadFrom() goes through Fusion and can be redirected to another assembly at a different path but with that same identity if one is already loaded in the LoadFrom context.
>
> LoadFile() doesn't bind through Fusion at all - the loader just goes ahead and loads exactly* what the caller requested. It doesn't use either the Load or the LoadFrom context.

And she also has another good post [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57143.aspx) detailing smoe of the advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Assembly.LoadFile or Assembly.Load methods